# mouse wheel zoom in Gnome3

Tags: shortcut-keys

In Gnome3 one can zoom in/out using Super&Alt&+/Super&Alt&-. I want to change the shortcuts in order to use my mouse wheel instead of the +/- keys. Does Gnome3 support this?

If not, I would like to use the xbindkeys to remap the keys. There is an  [example](https://blaxpirit.com/blog/19/zoom-the-screen-with-alt-scroll-in-kde.html) which works for KDE. But the problem is what to write in the .xbindkeysrc file. How should I modify the following command to make the script work for Gnome3?

```
"qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/kwin invokeShortcut view_zoom_in"
     Mod4+Super_L+ b:4
"qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/kwin invokeShortcut view_zoom_out"
     Mod4+Super_L+ b:5
```

Comment: The lack of this function is what mainly keeps me tied to Unity.

Comment: Under what package to we submit this feature request?